# Query about PowerShell precedence

Tags: powershell, operator-precedence

The following PowerShell appears to work:

> $Skip -and $Skip.Substring(0,1) -eq "y"

In that if $Skip is non-null (defined) and starts with "y", then True is returned. However, I'm pretty sure that if you did the same in C++, you'd be adding brackets around that string test because otherwise would it not be doing this?

> ($Skip -and $Skip.Substring(0,1)) -eq "y"

But that's definitely not what PowerShell is doing as the second line doesn't work as expected.

So how does PowerShell precedence work in this case?

Comment: If I am reading `get-help about_operator_precedence` correctly, then member access `.Substring()` is evaluated first, followed by `-eq`, then `-and`.

Comment: Thx for the tip - didn't know about that

Comment: And yes, the key point is that "-eq" has a higher precedence than "-and". One kind of assumed they were the same precedence